# Solution to quadratic equation in $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose that $p^k$ is a prime power $\ne 2 , 4$. Suppose $\exists x, y\in \Bbb Z$ not both divisible by p, for which $ax^2 + by^2 ≡ c\ (mod\ p^k )$.

Prove $\exists u, v \in \Bbb Z_p$ the $p$-adics  not both divisible by $p$, such that $au^2 + bv^2 = c$ in the p-adics.

What I did:

We look for $r,s\in \Bbb Z$ such that $u_k=x+rp^k, v_k=x+sp^k$ verifies: $au_k^2+bv_k^2\equiv  c (mod\ p^{k+1})$

So $ax^2+by^2 +2p^k(axr+bys)\equiv  c (mod\ p^{k+1})$,

So $\frac{ax^2+by^2-c}{p^k}+2(axr+bys)\equiv 0(\ mod\ p)$

Denote $\alpha :=  \frac{ax^2+by^2-c}{p^k}$

If we choose $p\nmid y$ we can take $r=0$, then $s=2^{-1}\alpha  (by)^{-1}$ which is well defined since $b$ and $p$ are not invertible $mod\ p$ (I suppose it is the case for b even there is no such assumption in the question).

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You don't need help here, you have noticed we need induction, from $ax_k^2 + by_k^2\equiv c\bmod p^k$ find $x_{k+1}\equiv x_k \bmod p^{k-v(a)},y_{k+1}\equiv y_k \bmod p^{k-v(b)}$ such that $ax_{k+1}^2 + by_{k+1}^2\equiv c\bmod p^{k+1}$. In general we would use the partial derivatives but here it is easier to expand the square root.